# Express route handler based with custom parameters

Tags: node.js, express

I'd like to output either HTML or JSON based on some req.headers data. For example: if req.headers.contentType == "application/json" I would return JSON, otherwise HTML.

```
var route = {
    html: function(req, res, next) {},
    json: function(req, res, next) {}
}

app.get('/test', route);
```

This obviously doesn't work. So I figured I'd need to have an intermediary function:

```
app.get('/test', _findRoute);

function _findRoute(req, res, next) {
    if(req.headers["content-type"] === "application/json") {
        return route.json;
    } else {
        return route.html;
    }
}
```

Which obviously also doesn't work because I don't actually have access to the route object at this point.

I can do:

```
app.get('/text', _findRoute(route));
```

But then I don't have access to the req object.

I actually have no idea how to proceed, so any ideas are very welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last version (`app.get('/text', _findRoute(route));`) will work if you only rewrite _findRoute a little.

```
function _findRoute (route) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    if(req.headers["content-type"] === "application/json") {
     route.json(req, res, next);
    }
    else {
     route.html(req, res, next);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it keeps my app stuck on loading. I'm considering a different (less elegant) solution with redirects, too, but if I could get yours to work that'd be brilliant! It gets to the point where you return route.html or route.json, node just doesn't seem to want to handle it. Any further thoughts?

Comment: Ah, I just copied your code, but now I see that you should really just call either route.json or route.html. I'll update my answer.